# I'm trying to initialize a DateTime in C# with a variable

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I'm pretty new here so my question may be silly, but I couldn't find anything similar to my question.
I'm programming in VS 2017 a winforms application.
I'm trying to initialize a DateTime with a variable year and month.
My code looks like this:

```
  int month = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
  month++;
  label1.Text = month.ToString();
  DateTime dt = new DateTime(year,month,1);
```

"month" changes everytime the user clicks on a combobox and selects a different month.
Same for the year but it doesnt crash,
and I created a label which shows what "month" contains (always showing 1-12 depending which month is clicked).

I get an out of range exception saying its not a valid DateTime.
(like month 13 or something but its not the case since I checked it via label)

A strange behaviour I could observe:
when the "month" variable is higher then 6 (I just added another "month++") it doesn't crash. It does crash though when I click on dezember since month is then 13. But that should be standard.

Comment: set a breakpoint on the DateTime line and look at year, month - see what they contain

Comment: Shouldn't you use the SelectedValue instead of SelectedIndex?

Comment: You cannot see that label, it crashes before it can be repainted.  So the diagnostic you added is useless.  Practice using the debugger, you add a minimum need to know how to set a breakpoint and view the value of a variable.

Comment: my guess is that year is not initialized. The point here is that DateTime(1900,6,1) (or whatever you want)works. So you are passing invalid year or month value

Comment: @pm100 thank you i didnt know about breakpoints this helped a lot!

Comment: @afonso the value is in words so "january",.....

Comment: @HansPassant i swapped the month variable for a static "6" to test the label, which i didnt show here sorry for the confusion. The breakpoint thing helped me understand the problem thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use display and value memeber

Create custom class like this:

```
class Int_String
{
    //important to have get set part
    public _int { get; set; }
    public _string { get; set; }
}
```

Now when creating form populate your combobox like this:

```
List<Int_String> myList = new List<Int_String>();
myList.Add(new Int_String { _int = 1, _string = "January" };
myList.Add(new Int_String { _int = 2, _string = "February" };
myList.Add(new Int_String { _int = 3, _string = "March" };
myList.Add(new Int_String { _int = 4, _string = "April" };
myList.Add(new Int_String { _int = 5, _string = "May" };
myList.Add(new Int_String { _int = 6, _string = "Juny" };
myList.Add(new Int_String { _int = 7, _string = "July" };
myList.Add(new Int_String { _int = 8, _string = "August" };
myList.Add(new Int_String { _int = 9, _string = "September" };
myList.Add(new Int_String { _int = 10, _string = "October" };
myList.Add(new Int_String { _int = 11, _string = "November" };
myList.Add(new Int_String { _int = 12, _string = "December" };

myComboBox.DisplayMember = "_string";
myComboBox.ValueMember = "_int";
myComboBox.DataSource = myList;
```

And now when you want to create `DateTime` variable you create it like this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(year, Convert.ToInt32(myComboBox.SelectedValue), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you get the month number from month name:
    new DateTime(1,month,1).ToString("MMMM");

Putting It All Together

```
int monthIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1; // Gets the Current Index
DateTime dt = new DateTime(year,month,1); // Defines a Date Off Of It
label1.Text = dt.ToString("MMMM"); // Gets Format of Month Name
dt = dt.AddMonths(1); // Adds a Month, This Might End Up in January of Next Year
```

Reference:
https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-month